# remote combobox gives AJAX call for the first time even if it is cascaded

Tags: extjs

Team,

I am having strange problem.

I am having two combo-boxes and I want to cascade one of them using the value of other.

So on select event of one combo-box I am getting another combo box and loading that store.

But what I have observed is the below case.

1. User selects first combo box value for very first time so store is loaded for second combo box.
2. When user selects second combo-box for very first time then AJAX call is made don't know why ?
3. Once again if user selects combo-box one then store is loaded for combo-box second
4. When user selects second combo-box once again AJAX call is not made (Why AJAX call is made for the first time)

I am not able to understand during step 2 why AJAX call is made for second combo as it is already loaded in step 1.

Code details

```
    xtype: 'combo',id='firstcombo', name: 'DEFAULT_VALUE' ,minChars:2, value: decodeHtmlContent('') ,width:200 ,listWidth:500, resizable: true,
 valueField : 'id', displayField: 'id', pageSize: 15,forceSelection:true, enableKeyEvents: true,
 store: new Ext.data.Store({reader: new Ext.data.CFQueryReader({id: 'NAME', 
            fields:[{name:'id', mapping:'id'}]}), 
            fields: [{name:'id', mapping:'id'}], 
            url:'server/ajax/Params'
            }

 }),
 listeners : {
         select:function(combo, record, index) {
            this.setRawValue(decodeHtmlContent(record.get('id')));
            cascadeFields();
        }



 xtype: 'combo',id='secondcombo', name: 'DEFAULT_VALUE' ,minChars:2, value: decodeHtmlContent('') ,width:200 ,listWidth:500, resizable: true,
 valueField : 'id', displayField: 'id', pageSize: 15,forceSelection:true, enableKeyEvents: true,
 store: new Ext.data.Store({reader: new Ext.data.CFQueryReader({id: 'NAME', 
            fields:[{name:'id', mapping:'id'}]}), 
            fields: [{name:'id', mapping:'id'}], 
            url:'server/ajax/Params',
            baseParam:{valuefirst:''}
            },
            listeners: {

                beforeload: function(store, options) {
                    var value = Ext.getCmp('fistcombo').value;
                    Ext.apply(options.params, {

                                valuefirst:value
                            });


                }, 

 }),
 listeners : {
         select:function(combo, record, index) {
            this.setRawValue(decodeHtmlContent(record.get('id')));
        }


function cascadeFields()
{

  var combo = Ext.getCmp('secondcombo');

  if(combo.store)
  {

  var store = combo.store;


  combo.setDisabled(true);
  combo.clearValue('');
  combo.store.removeAll();
  combo.store.load();        
  combo.setDisabled(false);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify no autoload on the stores:

> autoload: false

And on the combo boxes, you should set the querymode to local:

> queryMode: 'local'

Edit: You might want autoload on the first combo store though.

Comment: This is what I want 1) Combo box should always be loaded via ajax if they don't have any value so if cascading was done 2nd combo box upon expansion should not send AJAX request 2) if I use your option combo's are loaded when page is loaded that I donot want.

Comment: No, the options have the opposite effect :).
autoload: false -> You will have to load the store by yourself.
queryMode: 'local' -> The store will not load when you open the combos options the first time.
Please try the options, but as I said; You might want autoload set to true for the first store.

Comment: Please note that you use an equal sign ('=') to set your combos ID values.